# Suggest mp3 player plugin for a band website?

Tags: plugin-recommendation

like I said, can you suggest a wordpress jquery plugin for a mp3 player/playlist , this is actually for a band website  ...and it should have admin functionality where other users can just upload mp3 files or something like that

any cool suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I've used both [**WPaudio MP3 Player**](http://WPaudio%20MP3%20Player) and [**Flash MP3 Player**](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/flash-mp3-player/) So I can say that my clients found WPaudio MP3 Player easier to use and I found it easier to customize to look and feel, and to make it even easier to use you can create a small tinymce plugin (or as a media upload TAB) to add the shortcode.